# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in Python and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

There is problem with my code:

```
    if db_connection:
        cur_bal = db_connection.                                 \
            cursor().                                            \
            execute(f"""
                    select x from A
                      where x > {bound * 2};
                    """).                                        \
            fetchone()[0]
```

Python is writing: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.
What's wrong with this?

I think that problem with **fetchone()[0]** but I don't know exactly

Comment: It means there's no record in your database that matched the query.

Answer (score 1):

The error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" occurs when attempting to access an element of a variable that is `None`. In the provided code, the issue arises from the use of `fetchone()[0]`, where `fetchone()` returns `None`.

This situation usually happens when the query does not return any results from the database, causing `fetchone()` to return `None`. To resolve this error and handle the case when no results are returned, we need to implement a check for `None` before accessing the elements.

Try this:

```py
if db_connection:
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"""
                    SELECT x FROM A
                    WHERE x > {bound * 2};
                    """)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    if result is not None:
        cur_bal = result[0]
    else:
        # Handle the case when there are no matching records
        cur_bal = None  # or any other default value you want to assign
```

Comment: Thanks.

The problem was in result of script: it returned None